# Change background-color on every .white class and change back on .gray class with waypoint

Tags: css, if-statement, background-color, jquery-waypoints

I'm planning to change the background-color in my (`position: fixed;`) header menu with waypoint and I need you help with an IF ELSE statement.

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(direction) {
$('.gray').waypoint(function() {
if $("header").css('background-color', 'red');
} else {
$("header").css('background-color', 'white');
       }} );
});
```

Can you help me? And how can I put a smooth change?

Comment: You are giving a wrong value for your `if` statement the answer for the statement is either `true` or `false` so you need to ask a question with that kind of answer. When do you want the change in background to happen?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your if-else-block is completely missing.

```
$(document).ready(function(direction) {
    $('.gray').waypoint(function() {
        if ($(".red:in-viewport")) {
            $("header").css('background-color', 'red');
        } 
        else if ($(".white:in-viewport")) {
            $("header").css('background-color', 'white');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: ah ok... the if boolean should be like this: "the user is scroll above a class .red". oh je :) I hope you can understand my problem and do you can help me :) ?

Comment: I think he means when class `.red` is in viewport... http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: yes :) If class .red is in viewport (under the main navigation) the background-color from the mainnavigation is changing to red and if the mainnavigation over a div with the class .white = the background-color from the mainnavigation is white.

Comment: I have a page with different class areas: <div class="menu" style="position: fixed;"></div><div class="red"></div><div class="white"></div><div class="red"></div> etc... On every red class, if the mainnavogation div is over this div while the user is scrolling, the background-color should change in RED or WHITE (over the white classen)

Comment: thx a lot fot the new code. if i test the code, in my FF-console is a syntaxerror: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list else if ($(".white:in-viewport")){. i have put this code: $(document).ready(function(direction) {
    $('.gray').waypoint(function() {
        if ($(".red:in-viewport"))
            $("header").css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if ($(".white:in-viewport")){
            $("header").css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
});

Comment: Is the fixed menu over an RED div, the background-color from the main navi div should change in WHITE  and is the fixed menu over a white div, the background-color should change into RED, that`s my plan :) the whole thing should happen, if the user scroll down the website

Comment: There was a closing bracket missing in my code. I've fixed it.

Comment: My menu div `<header>` is on the top of the browser on scroll with "position:fixed". if this `<header>` over a div with the class RED the background-color from `<header>` should change into #fff. If the menu div `<header>` is over a div with the class WHITE the background-color from <header> should change into #ed0039. If the user  scroll down, the `<header>` pass different div`s on the page, every div has also a WHITE or a RED class - and i want to change the background-color from `<header>`